# Internet Explorer (7 and 8) sometimes just sit there with "Connecting..." after starting a debug

Tags: internet-explorer

This is getting really really annoying. 
I start debugging my web app using Visual Studio,  and regularly Internet Explorer just sits there saying "Connecting..." in one of the tabs, but if I open another tab I can usually go to the page that the first tab was going to, but sometimes not,but of course the new tab is a new thread so the debugger isn't attached to that one and I have to restart or detach/reattach the debugger until it works.

Seems to work after closing the ASP.Net Development Server that starts up, but not always.

Doesn't happen when I debug in Firefox, but I can't debug my JavaScript using VS from there.
Luckily I can debug Silverlight in Firefox which takes a bit of the pain off.

There are no extensions on IE as I use Firefox for pretty much everything bar testing.

Comment: "There are no extensions on IE" --> Are you /sure/? Tons of programs add extensions to IE without directly asking you for permission. Use Tools / Manage Add-ons to check for sure. Are you able to navigate the "spinning" tab to a different URL?

Comment: The spinning tab can't be used, just sits saying connecting no matter what url is entered.
After checking, it is more accurate to say there are a few extensions but all are disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem to have found a possible cause.

When I run CCleaner and clear out the IE cache, there is about 51meg removed. 
This is after I have used the "Delete Browsing History", so its not cleared all the time apparently.

Anyway, after using CCleaner to clean, it works until it reaches 50meg again, which is the max limit for my IE cache.

Maybe it's trying to figure out what to delete, don't know.